# Object definition scope

Tags: javascript

In javascript when you define an object literal, where does that object exist? Is that in the activation object of that function? I'm asking this to know if there is any technical difference between this or any other implications:

```
var global;
(function(){
  global={};

})();
```

or:

```
var global = {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object doesn't have any scope, so it doesn't make any difference where you create it.

However, if the object has methods, they can use local variables of the scope where they are created:

```
var global;

(function(){
  var local = 42;
  global = {
    aMethod: function() { alert(local); }
  };
})();
```

The local variable `local` only exists inside that scope, but the method in the object can use the variable as the method is created inside the scope.

The same works with an object created outside the scope, as long as the method is created inside the scope;

```
var global = {};

(function(){
  var local = 42;
  global.aMethod = function() { alert(local); }
})();
```

Comment: i know that object doesnt have its own scope but every object is defined on a scope, so if i understand you correcly there are absolutely no implications depending on which scope an object is defined

Comment: @AljošaSrebotnjak: Yes, the object itself is completely independent of the scope where it is created.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions have the exact same result, an empty global object. So no, there is no technical difference.

Comment: so it doesnt matter that in first case object literal was defined on different scope and it has reference from global scope pointing to him

Comment: No, there is no difference in the results